# How to replace a string in all records using Robo 3T?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t

I'm using MongoDB and Robo 3T. In some documents I have a field `parent` with the value `"0"` (string). I want to replace it with `"NA"`. In order to get all records I did:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
        var json = JSON.stringify( doc );
        if ( json.match(/"parent":"0"/) != null ) {
            printjson(doc);
        }
    });
```

Now, how can I replace the `"parent":"0"` with `"parent":"NA"` in all records?

**EDIT**: Another attempt:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
     var json = JSON.stringify( doc );
    if ( json.match(/"parent":"0"/) != null ) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {

              return (key === 'parent' && value === '0')
                ? value.replace('0', 'NA')
                : value;
            });
        }
        //doc = obj;
        printjson(obj);
    });
```

Which works. But updating the record by doing `doc = obj` doesn't work. How to fix it?

Comment: have you tried something like `if(doc.parent && doc.parent==="0"){doc.parent = "NA"}`

Comment: @cmgchess Well, it's nested so it does not work.